# Rails engine: where to store uploaded avatars?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, rails-engines

For a rails engine that uses devise and paperclip to let the user upload avatars, where is the best location to store the uploaded avatars?

Paperclip saves to `/public/system` by default.

Comment: Best location... for what purpose?

Comment: Usually it's `public/uploads` for development and some kind of CDN for production.

Comment: Amazon s3 - https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#storage